# Can I contact a corresponding professor before I accept a grad studies offer?

Tags: graduate-admissions, professorship, canada

A professor/department provided me with an offer for graduate studies in engineering in Canada.

The professor and I talked briefly before I applied, but the project(s) I would work on during my studies is still unclear.

Is it appropriate to contact the Prof. before I accept to talk about the projects again?

Comment: Will you have a masters degree when you start, or just a bachelors? And, if a bachelors, is it for doctoral study or masters?

Comment: Doctoral - but why does it matter

Comment: It matters in the US, and it matters what degree you already have if in the US. It also matters where you are. Different places in "North America" might have different answers also. There isn't a uniform system in such a big place.

Comment: Okay,  so back to the question: should I contact ?  So if Masters dont contact, if PhD contact ?

Comment: If you provide more information about your situation, you will likely get more (better?) answers. We can't guess and we can't answer for all the world.

Comment: What information do you need ?

Comment: For starters, you didn't respond to my second comment. Degree you hold. Degree you seek. More specific location if possible.

Comment: Bachelors, Masters - Held, PhD- Sought.  Electrical Eng.  North America.  Canada.

Comment: If exclusively Canada, then applying the tag might wake people up with specific knowledge there. Not me, sorry.

Comment: Is it really that different than USA.

Comment: Yes, there are (I believe) some important differences. Some of the Canadian processes are like US and some like UK. I don't want to give a possibly misleading answer.

Comment: How are UK and USA different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to contact prof before I accept to talk about the projects again ?

Absolutely, **yes.** This is particularly useful if you are joining a PhD program.

You can always email them, maybe even asking to schedule a meeting so that you can discuss your interests with them, and possible directions for your research. *You lose nothing by asking.* Make it clear that you haven't accepted the offer yet and would like to have a clearer idea of what you might work on, before making a decision.

Don't necessarily *expect* an immediate reply, however. Professors are extremely busy, and it could easily take a week or more for them to get back to you.

Comment: Okay,  so back to the question: should I contact ?  So if Masters dont contact, if PhD contact ?

Comment: If you know that you're going to work on projects beforehand, and you've already had a discussion with the professor, I would say that you should contact them, irrespective of whether you're joining a master's program or a PhD program.